# Is there any good terminal in Windows which can use git, docker, python, julia, jupyter lab from one window?

Tags: python, r, windows, docker, julia

I recenlty changed OS from Ubuntu to Windows.

When I used Linux, I confortably launched up git, docker/docker-compose, python, julia, R and other applications in bash. I used the terminator in Linux since the windows can be divided horizontally or vertically by just typing simple shortcuts.

Is there any recommneded terminal in Windows which meets my need?

I used Cmder but I was troubled to launch up python, julia or Jupyter lab/notebook. Also, vim interface is somewhat weired compared to that in Linux.
I expected the integrated terminal which can launch up datascience-related applications from one window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a terminal in Windows that meets your needs and allows you to launch various applications like Git, Docker/Docker Compose, Python, Julia, R, and others, you can try the following options:

***Windows Terminal:*** Windows Terminal is a modern, feature-rich terminal application that supports multiple tabs and panes. It can handle various shells, including PowerShell, Command Prompt, and the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). You can install and configure it from the Microsoft Store.

**Git Bash:** Git Bash is a terminal emulator for Windows that provides a bash shell experience. It comes bundled with Git for Windows and provides a familiar Unix-like environment. You can use it to launch Git, Python, Julia, and other applications. However, it doesn't have built-in support for dividing windows vertically or horizontally.

Comment: After installing vim, and git, and integrating these applications into PowerShell, I can launch most of the applications from Windows PowerShell (only with CUI movements). Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm.... this answer "smell" ChatGPT generated...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an IDE like VSCode is what you need.